Lambda and method parameters
this.appLauncherCore.forceJavaRuntimeDetection(this::onJREDetectionCompleted);
// some code here not related to the line above

private void onJREDetectionCompleted() {
    this.appLauncherCore.retrieveAvailableApplications(false,
            applicationGroups -> handleRefreshedAvailableApplicationsAndEnableAllMenuItems(applicationGroups),
            exception -> handleError(exception));
}

public void forceJavaRuntimeDetection(final JavaRuntimeDetectionCompletedHandler completedHandler) {

    this.executorService.submit(() -> {
        this.javaRuntimeService.detectJavaRuntime();
        completedHandler.onJREDetectionCompleted();
    });
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface JavaRuntimeDetectionCompletedHandler {

    /**
     * Callback informant de la fin de la détection des JRE installés sur le poste.
     */
    void onJREDetectionCompleted();
}

public void retrieveAvailableApplications(final boolean forceRefreshCache, 
    final ApplicationRefreshedHandler appRefreshedHandler, 
    final ErrorHandler errorHandler)

I don't understand at all how this code works.
As far as I understand forceJavaRuntimeDetection wants a JavaRuntimeDetectionCompletedHandler but I don't see how the current parameter can fit. How can this::onJREDetectionCompleted match the required type? Same for retrieveAvailableApplications.
I know basic lambda like in a forEach, map, etc. But those ones used as parameters?

I’ve posted an answer but you really should get a Java book.

Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

This is simple if you just line up the types.
JavaRuntimeDetectionCompletedHandler is a wrapper over a function that takes nothing and returns nothing. It’s called a Single Abstract Method, or SAM. SAM’s can be replaced with lambdas, which is why we can write this.appLauncherCore.forceJavaRuntimeDetection(this::onJREDetectionCompleted). This is simply another way of writing a lambda, using a Method Reference. It could also be written as as lambda () -> onJREDetectionCompleted(), which is precisely the SAM mentioned above. The compiler will create an anonymous class implementing the SAM interface, and pass it to the method forceJavaRuntimeDetection.
forceJavaRuntimeDetection takes the above, and invokes it in the executor submit method. The body of this method is a lambda that takes nothing () and returns nothing (since it calls the SAM mentioned before).
